# Wireless Keyboard RGB backlight design

Tags: led, rgb, keyboard, backlight

I am designing a split wireless keyboard with a 3.7V 2000mAh LiPo battery and using the BQ24075 for power management. I'm contemplating the use 32 of the SK6803 Mini-E for backlighting. Is this optimal in terms of power consumption and brightness? The datasheet indicates a minimum operating voltage of 3.7V. What happens when the battery supplies less voltage?

Are there better ways to create backlighting for this case? What do manufacturers of wireless keyboards typically do?

Comment: I think you are wanting to balance power and brightness, but I don't know how you are thinking about those; my mix isn't necessarily the same as yours.  If you go some  guard-band (zero to something) below the minimum voltage, then the LED's don't light up.  They have a minimum voltage required to start emitting light.  - Not an EE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't speak on what keyboard manufacturers do, but your solution likely won't work super well as it's currently described.

While single-cell lithium batteries typically have a nominal voltage of 3.7V, their actual range can vary from 4.2V (fully charged) to something like 3V or lower (discharged). Once the battery drops below 3.7V, it can't directly bias the LED (especially blue LEDs with higher forward voltages).

There's two solutions I thought of which would be better:

1. First, instead of using a single lithium cell, you could use two
   cells in series to double your voltage. Now your range is
   approximately 6V to 8.4V. With this solution, you'll need to use a
   different BMS solution than the BQ24075 and you'll need some
   circuitry (buck converter for efficiency) to step down the voltage
   to something like 4V going to the LED. Note, buck converters
   typically have a higher quiescent current draw than an LDO, so it
   may be wise to use an LDO that powers the logic/MCU and only enable
   the buck converter when the LEDs are turned on.
2. The second option is stepping up the voltage from the single lithium
   cell. Again, I'd recommend using a switching supply to step up the
   voltage going to the LEDs, but not powering the logic/MCU off of
   this rail for efficiency sake. The only issue with this solution is
   that the battery voltage could drop below the MCU's supply voltage
   range (commonly 3.3V). Therefore, I'd only recommend this solution
   if your microcontroller can operate throughout your battery's entire
   voltage range.

I'm sure there's other solutions that will work, but these seem pretty reasonable with battery life / efficiency in mind. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For all combinations of power consumption and brightnes, it is just statistically impossible that this is most optimal in respect to brigthness and power consumption. You need to define some numbers what efficiency you want or how bright or dim is acceptable with any given power consumption.

And the LED is specified to operate with voltage range down to 3.7V. If you go below that, technically even down to 3.699V, that's outside of defined operating conditions and the LED does not have to work properly or at all.